# Casting AnyObject to T

Tags: swift

Code:

```
class User
{
    class var BoolProperty: Bool
    {
        get {
            var anyObject: AnyObject? = getValue("BoolProperty")

            if let value = anyObject as? Bool {
                return value
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        }
        set(value) {
            setValue("BoolProperty", value: value)
        }
    }

    private class func getValue(key: String) -> AnyObject?
    {
        var store = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
        return store.objectForKey(key) as AnyObject?
    }
}
```

passes the test:

```
class UserTests: XCTestCase
{
    func testFields()
    {
        User.BoolProperty = true
        var result = User.BoolProperty
        XCTAssertEqual(true, result)
    }
}
```

but the following code doesn't pass the same test, which uses T instead of Bool for casting:

```
class User
{
    class var BoolProperty: Bool
    {
        get {
            return get("BoolProperty", defaultValue: false)
        }
        set(value) {
            setValue("BoolProperty", value: value)
        }
    }

    private class func getValue(key: String) -> AnyObject?
    {
        var store = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
        return store.objectForKey(key) as AnyObject?
    }

    private class func get<T>(key: String, defaultValue: T) -> T
    {
        var anyObject: AnyObject? = getValue(key)

        if let value = anyObject as? T {
            return value
        }
        else {
            return defaultValue
        }
    }
}
```

it seems, that for some reason `if let value = anyObject as? T` always returns false when casting to T.

In C# this is a classic example of working with untyped collections and I was wondering what's the right approach to achieve the same in Swift.

Comment: This scenario now works in Xcode6-Beta6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that an `NSNumber` is not a `Bool`. It looks like a `Bool`, and it can be converted to a `Bool`, but it's really a different type. Your `anyObject` is really an `NSNumber`, and asking for it to be `as? T` where `T` is `Bool` is too far. That's still likely a compiler bug, because it should be the same as a generic as without, but it's where the problem is happening.

You need to specialize the generic function to `NSNumber`:

```
get {
return Bool(get("BoolProperty", defaultValue: NSNumber(bool: false)))
}
```

It's still probably worth opening a radar. It shouldn't behave differently with and without the generic.

That said, part of the trouble is the use of `AnyObject`. A `Bool` is not an `AnyObject`. It's an `Any`. When you try to assign it to an `AnyObject`, it gets converted into an `NSNumber`. I don't know of any documentation of this; I've worked it out empirically in playgrounds. Compare the results of `let a:AnyObject = false` and `let a:Any = false`.

In theory, this should fix it all:

```
var anyObject: Any? = getValue(key)
```

But it currently crashes the compiler.

Comment: thank you. I've made it working using NSString to store String values and NSNumber to store Bool values.